# Dataflow Batch Job Stuck in GroupByKey.create()

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a batch dataflow pipeline that I have ran without issue many times on a subset of our data, with approximately 150k rows of input.  I have now attempted to run on our full dataset of approximately 300M rows.  A crucial part of the pipeline performs a GroupByKey of the input records resulting in (I believe) ~100M keys.

The relevant part of the pipeline looks like this:

```
// Results in map of ~10k elements, 160MB in size
PCollectionView<Map<String, Iterable<Z>>> sideData = ...

...

.apply(ParDo.named("Group into KV").of(
    new DoFn<T, KV<String, T>>() { ... }
))
.apply("GBK", GroupByKey.create())
.apply(ParDo.named("Merge Values").withSideInputs(sideData).of(
    new DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<T>>, V>() { ... }
))
```

Two times I have run this pipeline and each time the job has stalled after running fine for more than 16 hours.  The first time I ran it using 10 `n1-highmem-8` and the second time using 6 `n1-highmem-16` instances.

I can tell from the Dataflow job console that the `Group into KV` ParDo completes just fine and outputs 101,730,100 elements with a size of 153.67 GB.  The step detail for the `GBK` transform says that there were 72,091,846 and 72,495,353 elements added in the first and second attempts, respectively.  At this point the `GBK` transform is still in the running phase, but the CPU on all the machines drops to zero and the pipeline is effectively stalled. All future stages in the pipeline all stop incrementing element counts.  I can ssh into the machines to look at the various logs under /var/log/dataflow/ but there doesn't appear to be anything out of the ordinary.  No errors in the cloud console and the GC logs don't seem to indicate memory issues.

At this point I'm at a bit of a loss to know what to do next. I have read that using a `Combiner` instead of using the `GroupByKey` could yield better scalability.  And with a little refactoring I could make it so that the code is commutative so that the Combiner would be an option.  I'm somewhat hesitant to attempt that as each time I have tried to run this pipeline it has cost me ~$250 in wasted cloud compute time.

My questions are:

- What are the recommended ways to try to figure out what the pipeline is doing when it appears to be stalled?  Should I do a `kill -QUIT <pid>` on the java process to get a stack trace, and if so, where would it go?
- Does anyone have any theories about why this pipeline would suddenly stall without any errors or warnings?

IDS of aforementioned jobs:

- 2016-09-02_10_56_46-679417604641749922
- 2016-09-03_15_52_32-6019142684328835224

Comment: Have you checked the Compute Engine logs to see if the workers are reporting any issues?  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/troubleshooting-your-pipeline

Comment: @Frances There are no errors in the logs. Lots of workers report "Finished processing state s20 with 0 errors in nnnn.nn seconds", which all seem to wrap up around the same time that the job became idle -- which seems highly correlated. I do not have an understanding of which part of my pipeline is stage s20, however.  That being said, there were still parts of the pipeline in the running phase and some still in the waiting phase. There was definitely work to be done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one worker may be either stuck or taking a long time to run the `DoFn` code after the `GroupByKey`. The most likely cause of this is a "hot key" (having significantly more values than other keys). You could add an Aggregator to the `DoFn` and report the size of the Iterable while running, something like this:

```
private static class MyDoFn extends KV<String, Iterable<T>>, V> {

  private static final Logger LOG =
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilterTextFn.class);
  private final Aggregator<Long, Long> maxIterableSize =
      createAggregator("maxIterableSize", new Max.MaxLongFn());

  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    long numElements = 0;
    for (T value : c.element().getValue()) {
      maxIterableSize.addValue(numElements++);
      if (numElements == 100) {
        LOG.warning("Key {} has > 100 values", c.element().getKey());
      }
      ... // the rest of your code inside the loop
    }
  }
}
```

The above will add a counter showing the maximum number of elements on a single key, and also report to Cloud Logging any key that has more than 100 values (feel free to adjust the threshold as seems reasonable -- the single hot key likely has *many* more elements than any other key).

The other possibility is that there is something in the code for that `DoFn` that is either hanging or really slow on some specific set of data. You could try connecting to the worker that is processing this one item and seeing what it is working on (using `kill -QUIT <pid>` as you mentioned).

Comment: I think you might have found it. Most of my keys (all in the sample set I was using) are very well distributed and have at most 15-20 records per key. I did a query on the full dataset and found a key with ~1.6MM hits!  However, I still am left wondering why the CPU wasn't thrashing on one of the nodes (indicating aggressive GC) and the logs don't mention anything about OOM.

Comment: The CPU and memory usage would depend on the code in the `DoFn`. The elements can be streamed in, so unless the `DoFn` tries to store them all in memory an OOM isn't expected. As far as CPU -- are these multi-core machines? Since the processing happens in a single thread, it could at worst use 1/#cores, which may be pretty small.